# Remove HTML Tags python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have looked everywhere for a solution to my problem, but none of them seem to work. Essentially, I want to know the simplest way to remove HTML tags from a string. For example,

```
PriceTag = Soup.find_all(class_="text-robux-lg wait-for-i18n-format-render")
print(PriceTag)
```

This returns `[<span class="text-robux-lg wait-for-i18n-format-render">1,250</span>]` which is very much expected, but I don't know how to take 'PriceTag' and remove the HTML tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `.text` method:

```
print(PriceTag.text)
```

This will remove the HTML tags and extract the inner text of the selected element.

If this is a `find_all`, you need to use a for-loop to traverse:

```py
for price_tag in PriceTag:
    print(price_tag.text)
```

Comment: Wow I feel embarrassed lol, works perfectly. I just also had to change 'find_all' to 'find'. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not that experienced but i'll have a go at your question

```
for price in Pricetag:
    print(price.text.strip())
```